# can spark cluster be used instead of a java rest application

Tags: rest, apache-spark, jax-rs

We have an application, which is built on java/jax-rs which listens to rest calls on a port, and we use tomcat to deploy our application, the api which listens to this post call, dumps the data into mysql after some nominal filtering, and then one timer(java.util.Timer) thread  queries the data every second and process it and stores into anther db. now as the frequency/volume  of the incoming data is quite huge the mysql is chocking up sometime. we are thinking to go for a master master replication ( as the load is on insert , so master slave wont be of any help) which may work for some time , but the algorithms that run are also pretty cpu intensive.

So we are thinking about a permanent alternative, that brings spark into the scenario, we already have a running hotonworks which is running for hadoop and hbase.

So I wanted to know, if we have a spark cluster( say running on GCP) and can setup spark such a way that it will be listening to the same port( we dont want any effect at the client end) and instead of a java application running on tomcat, spark  will run small batch jobs in 1 sec interval and  do the rest of the process . I know that spark is able to connect with several spouts like kafka, jdbc or from file etc. But can it replace a rest api ??

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you might know Spark has its own REST endpoint (spark-jobserver) that provide the ability to trigger a Spark job with an HTTP request and retrieve the results.
But due to low level API of the spark-jobserver I think this is not the best decision to completely replace your application with it.
You will get much better results using your own endpoint with domain specific REST abstraction. Instead of making low level post requests:

```
POST/jars/appName
POST/context/appCtx
POST/data/jobParams
POST/jobs/myJob
```

You will still make your domain specific requests:

```
POST/add-user 
{
     email: 123@gmail.com
     name: Alex
}
```

And in your application you will just start your small batch spark jobs (with help of SparkLauncher as an example).

So your code might look like this (I will use spring-mvc for simplicity):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    new SparkLauncher()
              .setAppResource(<path to jar>)
              .setMaster("yarn-cluster") 
              .setDeployMode("client")
              .setVerbose(true)
              .setMainClass("com.test.Main")               
              .startApplication();
}
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough for your time,

Comment: I cant thank you enough @ruslangm  for your time ,
I have one more doubt, lets assume the frequency of my job is one second, and the amount of data in this one second is also big enough, so I just cant buffer that data inside the app, also my bottleneck was the mysql, so I may go for something like redis, but I believe spark can not directly access redis, although I can fetch it with the app itself, do you suggest any better alternative, so that we can skip this step all together , like in storm these are possible .

Comment: You could try this https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis